# Getting lsinitramfs to boot into an encrypted file system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, encryption, luks

I followed the directions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Btrfs_subvolumes_with_swap). I've been using the LiveCD and I cannot for the life of me persuade Ubuntu to create a initramfs file that would be willing to decrypt my LUKS file-system. I'm having no problems getting past GRUB.

Help? I have a feeling we can make this work though.

When I get to the initramfs stage, I am able to run cryptsetup but I get this error message:

```
device-mapper: table: 252:0 crypt error allocating tfm
```

I also got a message saying "Check that kernel supports aes-xts-plain64 cipher"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out!

I adapted this guide, mostly just adding stuff until it worked:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemOnIntrepid

I modified the files a bit from that guide, but otherwise followed it.

Just in case, I added these modprobe lines to /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/cryptoroot:

```
modprobe -q dm_crypt
modprobe -q sha256_generic
modprobe -q sha256
modprobe -q aes_generic
modprobe -q aes
modprobe -q cbc
modprobe -q xts
modprobe -q aes
modprobe -q aes_x86_64
```

Which gives:

```
    PREREQ="udev"

prereqs()
{
        echo "$PREREQ"
}

case $1 in
# get pre-requisites
prereqs)
        prereqs
        exit 0
        ;;
esac
#This line from the Encrypted Entrepid tutorial didn't work for me
#/bin/loadkeys -q /etc/console-setup/boottime.kmap.gz
modprobe -q dm_crypt
modprobe -q sha256
modprobe -q sha256_generic
modprobe -q aes_generic
modprobe -q aes
modprobe -q cbc
modprobe -q xts
modprobe -q aes
modprobe -q aes_x86_64    
# The following command will ensure that the kernel is aware of
# the partition before we attempt to open it with cryptsetup.
/sbin/udevadm settle

if grep -q splash /proc/cmdline; then
    /bin/chvt 1
fi
/sbin/cryptsetup luksOpen CRYPTOROOT cryptoroot
if grep -q splash /proc/cmdline; then
       /sbin/usplash -c &
       sleep 1
fi
```

For the file above (local-top), the CRYPTROOT line needs to be changed.

I used a keyfile, so my line looked like this:

```
/sbin/cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxx --key-file /my_keyfile.bin cryptoroot
```

The keyfile isn't necessary. The luksHeader can be opened by a password (just remove the key-file option). That said, if you do include the file, don't use /dev/sdXy.

To /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptoroot I just added these lines:

```
# Comment out this line
# cp /etc/console-setup/boottime.kmap.gz ${DESTDIR}/etc/console
# If you add a key-file
# cp /my_keyfile.bin ${DESTDIR}/
copy_exec /bin/loadkeys /bin
copy_exec /bin/chvt /bin
copy_exec /sbin/cryptsetup /sbin
copy_exec /sbin/blkid /sbin
copy_exec /sbin/lsmod /sbin
copy_exec /sbin/cat /sbin
copy_exec /sbin/dmsetup /sbin
```

Which gives:

```
PREREQ=""

prereqs()
{
        echo "$PREREQ"
}

case $1 in
prereqs)
        prereqs
        exit 0
        ;;
esac

if [ ! -x /sbin/cryptsetup ]; then
        exit 0
fi

. /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions

# Comment out this line
# cp /etc/console-setup/boottime.kmap.gz ${DESTDIR}/etc/console
    # If you add a key-file
    # cp /my_keyfile.bin ${DESTDIR}/
    copy_exec /bin/loadkeys /bin
    copy_exec /bin/chvt /bin
    copy_exec /sbin/cryptsetup /sbin
    copy_exec /sbin/blkid /sbin
    copy_exec /sbin/lsmod /sbin
    copy_exec /sbin/cat /sbin
    copy_exec /sbin/dmsetup /sbin
```

Also all these files must be marked executable.

```
chmod +x /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptoroot
chmod +x /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/cryptoroot
```

Add these to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules:

```
dm_mod
dm_crypt
sha256_generic
sha256_ssse3
aes_generic
cbc
aes_x86_64
xts
```

It was relatively easy!

Run update-initramfs -u -k all

Then we need to create a custom GRUB entry in my case because os-prober won't detect a file system on BTRFS. The arch entry will help there.

This is what mine looks like:

```
menuentry "System shutdown" {
        echo "System shutting down..."
        halt
}

menuentry "System restart" {
        echo "System rebooting..."
        reboot
}    

menuentry 'Ubuntu Linux try 1' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    load_video
     set gfxpayload=keep
     insmod gzio
     insmod part_msdos
     insmod cryptodisk
     insmod luks
     insmod gcry_rijndael
     insmod gcry_sha256
     insmod btrfs
     insmod ext2
     cryptomount -u [UUID of sdXY]
     set root='cryptouuid/[UUID of sdXY]'
     if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='cryptouuid/[UUID of sdXY]'  [UUID of /dev/mapper/cryptoroot]
     else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root [UUID of /dev/mapper/cryptoroot]
     fi
     echo    'Loading Linux linux-lts ...'
     #I use btrfs so...
     linux    btrfs path    root=UUID=[UUID of /dev/mapper/cryptoroot] rw rootflags=subvol=/btrfs/path/to/root cryptdevice=/dev/disk/by-uuid/[UUID of sdXY]':cryptroot quiet modprobe.blacklist=pcspkr profile
     echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
     initrd  path/initrd.img
    }

    ##I was able to boot without this kernel option but some guides suggested it: ##cryptopts=target=cryptrootname,source=/dev/sdXY
```

It's official: Ubuntu can boot into Arch's encrypted file system! I did much googling and I'm not sure anyone else had cracked this one, at least not in a few years.

Comment: If you are satisfied with this solution, please [accept your own answer](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/).

Comment: Thank you--still learning the ropes around here! I accepted this answer but actually can't get it to work on my other computer! So I may unaccept it soon!